AWS MWAA Set Up, Dags not visible in UI
I am trying to setup AWS MWAA, followed the instruction as per the documents but still the dags are not visible in the UI.S3 bucketAirflow UI
I tried setting up the AWS MWAA but no dags visible, i checked logs but nothing is visible, bucket versioning is enabled and blocked all public access too
